# ZF - Check whether request is forwarded from another action

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller

I'm using Zend Framework and come up with a situation of forwarding a request to another action in same controller.

> I'm forwarding the request from *create* to *save*. What I want to do is to check (from saveAction) whether the request is forwarded or a direct request (without using any additional variables or parameters)

`init()` function will be triggered twice for each forwarding (one for *create* and one for *save*), and it would be better check from `init()` too.

```
class Cms_UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        // some code here
    }

    public function createAction() {

        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            // forwarding to cms/user/save
            return $this->_forward('save');
        }

        // do some stuff for POST request
    }

    public function saveAction() {
        // I want to check whether the request is
        // forwarded from 'createAction' or from any action
        // or a direct request to cms/user/save
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

```
public function lastAction(){
    $request=$this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $request['action']; //you can get corresponding actions here
}
public function testAction(){
    return $this->_forward('last');
}
```

Comment: That worked!!! thanks man. FYI, I've used a short cut method `$this->getRequest()->getParam('action')` that will give 'test', and `$this->getRequest()->getActionName()` will give 'last' :)

Comment: Great work @Munawer Aziz and rajukoyilandy ...your previous collegue..unnikrishnan